# Special Zero Divisor in Ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring.
A non-zero $a\in R$ is a called a zero divisor if there exits a non-zero $b\in R$ such that $ab=0$.
$a\in R$ is called an idempotent if $a^2 =a$.
$a\in R$ is called a nilpotent if there exists $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a^n=0$.
It is clear and well-known that both idempotent and nilpotent are zero divisor.

Is there any other special type of zero divisor in a ring?

Comment: How are idempotents always zero divisors? In any integral domain $R$, which has no zero-divisors, $1$ is an idempotent.

Comment: Any idempotent not equal to $0$ or $1$ is a zero divisor, since $a(1-a)=0$.

Comment: @DonThousand, thanks for pointing out my blind spot. What you say is indeed true. I should have excluded the 1 as what pre-kidney have done.

Comment: I disagree with the votes that it is “too broad.”  Yes, it is _open ended_, but it is quite focused.

Comment: Every element of a minimal prime ideal is a zero divisor, and this observation contains the case of both nilpotents and non-trivial idempotents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A slight generalization of the idempotent case:

Any element $a\ne 0$ that is not a root of unity, but fulfils $a^n=a$ for some $n>1$, is a zero divisor:

Proof: $0 = a^n-a = a(a^{n-1}-1)$. Since by assumption $a$ is not a roof of unity, $a^{n-1}-1\ne 0$.

**Edit:** Thinking further about it, one can generalize this even more:

Every non-zero non-unit element $a$ that fulfils $a^n=ua$ for some unit $u$ and $n>1$ is nilpotent.

Proof: $0 = a^n - ua  = (a^{n-1}-u)a$. Now if we had $a^{n-1}=u$, then $a^{n-1}u^{-1}=1$, therefore $a$ would be a unit with $a^{-1} = a^{n-2}u^{-1}$. But by assumption, $a$ is not an unit, therefore $a$ is nilpotent.

Comment: At that rate, you may as well use elements that satisfy an integer polynomial equation, having zero constant term.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for examples of zero divisors that are neither idempotent nor nilpotent. Perhaps the simplest example of such an element occurs in the ring $\mathbb Z/6$, the ring of integers modulo $6$, where $2$ is a zero divisor ($2\cdot 3=0$) yet it is not nilpotent, since no power of $2$ is divisible by $6$.

An example of a different nature occurs in matrix rings, such as the ring of $n\times n$ matrices with real coefficients. Then, any matrix with determinant $0$ is a zero divisor, and the vast majority of such matrices is neither idempotent nor nilpotent. In other words, another class of zero divisors are the singular matrices in any matrix ring.

Comment: I think OP is looking for classes of zero divisors, not just off-handed examples.

Comment: Yes, as what @DonThousand have highlighted, I am looking for other special classes of zero divisors, not a specific example.

Comment: I have provided such a class - the class of singular matrices in any matrix ring.